# How to override shipping-addres item in Magento2.3?

Tags: magento2.3

I am trying to add the company name of customer to the shipping address.
I tried overriding the template in the "Magento_Checkout" module under

> design/frontend/../../Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

Also tried

> design/frontend/../../Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

But neither of them seem to work.

Is there any other way of overriding this template in Magento 2.3?
[image: -]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override this file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

here in your custom theme..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html

And, You can override below file

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/billing-address/details.html

here in your custom theme..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/billing-address/details.html

Then you can add company name there and then you need to run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if this will helpful to you.

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help!